# SQL installation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just installed postgresql9.0.3 and when I went to the bin to run psql it asked for a password....I am typing the password which I gave at the time of installation but nothing is being written on the screen...when I press enter the psql closes.

What could be the problem?

Comment: @albin can u plz solve my problem

Comment: On which OS are you installing PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason seems to be that psql will usually assume your PostgreSQL user name is the same as your login name. If it's a new installation of PostgreSQL, you probably have only one username defined, though, and that's "postgres".

```
psql -U postgres
```

You might also need [the -d, -h, and -p options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).